# Displaying text if post was within 5 hours

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I have the following string.

```
$timeago = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );
print $timeago;
```

This returns results that looks like this.

1 min, 1 hour, 1 week, 1 month, and 1 year.

I am trying to figure out how I can make this work using an `if` statement to detect if the post has been posted within the past 5 hours, and if it has make it echo "**NEW**" but if not, don't echo anything.

**EDIT:** 
I tried the following with no success... I am getting confused on how to make it check for the hours portion as well as the number portion I guess.

```
$timeago = human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') );
print $timeago;
if( $timeago >= 0 && $timeago <= 5 )
{
    print 'NEW';
}
```

Comment: `$timeago =strtotime(date('Y-m-d')) - strtotime('your post date');
print ($timeago/3600);` now you get difference in hour. I am not word press expert so i give it as an example

Comment: @A-2-A I edited my question!

Comment: I don't know the functions of wordpress, sorry. A general idea is given above in my comment  and next you can do `if( ($timeago/3600) <=5 )
{
    print 'NEW';
}`

Comment: @A-2-A nah, after tinkering with this for a couple of minutes it doesn't seem to do anything to solve the issue I am having you can real about the human_time_diff function here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/human_time_diff

Comment: aren't you able to get your post date?

Comment: @A-2-A the function in the question does this..

Comment: Wait for some wordpress experts or others to get your problem resolved.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it manually like below:

```
$from = current_time('timestamp') - 1000000;
$to = current_time('timestamp');
$diff = (int) abs($to - $from);
$hours = round($diff / HOUR_IN_SECONDS);
if ($hours <= 1)
    $hours = 1;
echo $hours; //OP = 278 (278 hours)
```